# Derived Control: Implement CreateHandle

Tags: c#, winforms

Как правильно реализовать производный от `System.Windows.Forms.Control` класс, в котором используется собственный механизм создания дескриптора окна?

Cкажем, есть сторонняя библиотека, создающая окно *Windows* и возвращающая его дескриптор.

А затем привязать полученный дескриптор окна *Windows* к контролу (т. е. сохранить его `NativeWindow/Handle`)?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WinFormsApp {
  public class MyControl : Control {

    [DllImport("MyLib.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateWindow();

    protected override void CreateHandle() {

      // Здесь нужно обязательно вызвать base.CreateHandle()
      // для изменения private field state,
      // но он сам создает handle?

      var handle = CreateWindow();
      // Почему-то происходит повторный вход в CreateHandle
      // в момент вызова CreateWindow,
      // вероятно из Control/NativeWindow WndProc.

      // Как теперь ассоциировать полученный handle с MyControl,
      // т. е. что-то вроде:
      (WindowTarget as NativeWindow)?.AssignHandle(handle);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Control.FromHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) Это вы искали?

Comment: Метод Control.FromHandle возвращает объект типа Control, который создал это окно и сохранил ссылку на себя через Windows API SetWindowLong) – это не по теме, читайте внимательно исходный вопрос!

Comment: Судя по вашему коду вообще не понятно зачем вам тогда `Control`,если вы пытаетесь затереть его дескриптор.

Comment: static extern IntPtr CreateWindow() создает окно Windows и возвращает его дескриптор. В приложении Windows Forms с этим окном проще всего работать через функционал класса Control, используя Handle. Исходный вопрос: "Как правильно реализовать производный от System.Windows.Forms.Control класс, в котором используется собственный механизм создания дескриптора окна?"

Comment: Для того что бы понять как вам помочь, объясните, зачем вы хотите затирать дескриптор контрола, которым вы хотите далее управлять?

Comment: Я не пытаюсь затереть дескриптор окна Windows, смотрите внимательно шаблон кода и комментарии в нем.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76654/discussion-between-mega-web-and-yami).